# How would I create my own test case to figure out why this code returns the correct answer half of the time?

Tags: c#, .net, integer, testcase

I'm trying to figure out why if I change my values from 4 & 2 to something like 4 & 3, it doesn't compute the averages correctly.

I would like to know 2 things.

How to run a testcase for something as simple as this, and how to fix my code to where it will average out two numbers correctly every time.

```
using System;

public class MathUtils
{
    public static double Average(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b) / 2;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Average(4, 2));
    }
}

// right now returns 3 which is correct
```

Comment: Is this real life or homework?

Comment: You're adding two integers and dividing by a 3rd integer (the literal '2').  The way most strongly-typed programming languages works means this will be performed using integer arithmetic.

Comment: How would you like to test it? Using which unit testing framework? Is visual studio unit testing ok?

Comment: Yes visual studio is ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to :

```
public static double Average(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b) / 2.0; // will be incorrect for edge case with int-overflow - see Edit 
}
```

Reason:
If you add up two integers you get an integer. If you divide an integer by an integer you get another integer by default - not a float or double. The parts after the `.` are discarded.

---

Edit:
As Hans Passant pointed out, you can get an overflow error in case both ints add up to more than a int can handle - so casting (at least one of) them to double is the smarter move

```
    return ((double)a + b) / 2; // .0 no longer needed.
```

---

You need to get some non-integers in the mix to get the .xxxx part as well.

As for the testcase - that depends on the testing framework you are using.
You should probably consider testcases of (`int.MinValue`, `int.Minvalue`) , (`int.MaxValue`, `int.MaxValue`) and some easy ones `(0,0)`, `(1,1)`, `(1,2)`

For how to detect the error: get some C# experience - or use intermediate variables and breakpoints and a debugger to see what goes wrong where.

This here:

```
public static double Average(int a, int b)
{
    var summed = a + b;
    var avg = summed / 2;

    return avg;
}
```

in debugging would point out the error quite fast.

Comment: Average(int.MaxValue, 1)

Answer (score 1):

```
return ((double)a + b) / 2; //simple
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more context or explanation of how your answer works?